How can I check if the rigidbody is moving
The problem is that rb.velocity probably returns too small values
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float sprintSpeed = 10f;
    public float crouchSpeed = 2.5f;
    public float jumpForce = 2f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 200f;
    public float dashSpeed = 100f;
    public float dashCooldown = 12f;
    public bool isGrounded;
    public bool isJumpAllowed = false;
    public KeyCode dashKey = KeyCode.Q;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    private bool isJumping = false;
    private bool isCrouching;
    private bool isSprinting;
    [SerializeField] private bool isDashing;
    [SerializeField] private float lastDashTime = 0f;
    
    private Player player = null;
    
    public void Init(Player pPlayer)
    {
        player = pPlayer;
    }
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        lastDashTime = -dashCooldown;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void UpdatePMC()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded && isJumpAllowed)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, jumpForce, 0f), ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            isJumping = true;
        } else {
            isJumping = false;
        }
        
        if ((Input.GetKeyDown(dashKey) && isGrounded) && Time.time - lastDashTime >= dashCooldown)
        {
            isDashing = true;
            lastDashTime = Time.time;
        }
        
        playerAnim();
    }
    
    public void FixedUpdatePMC()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = (transform.right * x + transform.forward * z).normalized;
        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + move * sprintSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            isSprinting = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
        {
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + move * crouchSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            isCrouching = true;
        }
        else if (isDashing)
        {
            Vector3 dashDirection = transform.forward;
            RaycastHit dashHit;

          
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, dashDirection, out dashHit, dashSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime))
            {
                rb.MovePosition(dashHit.point);
            }
            else
            {
                rb.MovePosition(transform.position + dashDirection + dashDirection * dashSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                //rb.MovePosition(transform.position + move + dashDirection * dashSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            }
           
            isDashing = false;
        } else if (isJumping)
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + move * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            isSprinting = false;
            isCrouching = false;
        }

        
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        
        
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f, groundMask))
        {
            Vector3 targetPosition = hit.point;
            targetPosition.y = transform.position.y; 

            Vector3 direction = (targetPosition - transform.position).normalized;
            Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.fixedDeltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void playerAnim()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player is moving: " + rb.velocity);
            if (rb.velocity != Vector3.zero)
            {
                if (isSprinting)
                {
                    player.AnimController.SetMovementState(MovingState.Running);
                } 
                else
                {
                    player.AnimController.SetMovementState(MovingState.Walking);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                player.AnimController.SetMovementState(MovingState.Idle);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            player.AnimController.SetMovementState(MovingState.Idle);
        }
    }
}

I also tried comparing with sqrMagnitude but the result is basically the same.
If I'm comparing velicity with vector. Sometimes the animation switches for a split second, because even if the player is not moving, there is still some movement.

Have you tried comparing against a very small but non-zero threshold like 0.01?

Your code might do as well funny things when your character is falling/ jumping since you play an idle animation regardless when you are not grounded

So the problem was probably caused by the fact that I was using MovePosition. After I reworked the script to use velocity for movement. So everything works as it should.
@Zibelas I know the idle animation when I'm not on the ground looks a bit weird, but it was only there temporarily. It's already been replaced by the fall animation.
